# Selecting middle DOM items with JQuery

Tags: jquery

In the code below I have the 3rd li element selected. I'm curious how to modify the JQuery code to select any number of the *next* li tags along with the 3rd one. Basically I have the 3rd one selected and am curious what code I could add to keep making further simultaneous selections.

```
<article id="post1">
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>Tab1</li>
        <li>Tab2</li>
        <li>Tab3</li>
        <li>Tab4</li>
        <li>Tab5</li>
        <li>Tab6</li>
        <li>Tab7</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</article>


    <script>
    $('#post1 > nav > ul > li:nth-child(3)').css('color','green');
    </script>
```

Comment: So, you want to select the third `li` element and its following siblings?

Comment: Not all of them .I want to know how to control the number being selected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are looking for [`.slice`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/):

```
$('#post1 > nav > ul > li').slice(2, 3+x).css('color','green');
```

where `x` is the number of following siblings you want to select.

Comment: Thanks . I was fumbling about trying to use similar syntax in the children method.